# How to change set command head path

Tags: macos, shell, fish

I appended a new path to my $fish_user_path because I wanted to use the newer version of php I had installed there.

```
set -U fish_user_path /Applications/XAMPP/xampfiles/bin $fish_user_paths
```

Now I realise I didn't want to do that, I want to remove the path

```
set -e -U fish_user_paths[1]
```

This gives me an error from ***head*** - **Unknown option: n**

I believe the cause of this is that I am now using head from the path I added. But I can't remove the path because of the error.

Is there either another way to remove the path or can I temporarily specify which version of head to use?

Comment: Running `set -e -u fish_user_paths[1]` does not execute `head` or any other external command since `set` is a builtin. That error is going to be from your `fish_prompt` or related function (e.g., `fish_preexec`). There is something you're not telling us because that attempt to erase the first entry should have worked regardless of any errors you saw as a consequence of functions that run as a byproduct of executing a command. Out of curiosity do you really have a `head` program in the directory you added? That seems odd.

Comment: I've kept trying things and found something that works, removing the -U flag from the erase line. Btw no I don't have a head program in that directory but it does seem to have some significance because I added other dirs to the path and didn't get the same error.

Comment: Boy, this is where some tracing mechanism (bash `set -x`) would be handy.